# Obter feriados nacionais

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e gostaria de saber se há algum meio de obter os feriados nacionais.

Por exemplo: Alguma API da agenda do Google onde posso obter algum XML para consumir..

Comment: Por webservice conheço o [Multitabelas](http://www.multitabelas.com.br/docs/CIDADES.php).

Comment: Atende. Coloca seu comentário como resposta que eu já aceito.

Comment: O [Multitabelas possui um Webservice em PHP](https://multitabelas.speedyrevolution.com.br/#/cidades_feriados_docs). Nele é possível obter não apenas feriados nacionais, como também feriados regionais.

Comment: A [Elekto](http://elekto.com.br/) (aviso: é minha empresa) fornece uma API JSONP, de uso gratuito, explicada em detalhes [aqui](http://elekto.com.br/Blog/ComoConsumirApiDeCalendarios). É a API que é usada em nossa [ferramenta de prazos em dias úteis](http://elekto.com.br/Tools/Prazos). O foco, no entanto, é o mercado financeiro. A ferramenta está no ar desde 2012-05, hospedada em São Paulo (menos latência).

Comment: O Grande problema no Brasil são os feriados municipais e a quantidade de cidades existentes. Só encontrei uma API que tenha feriados de todos os municípios. Estou usando e tem funcionado bem: http://www.calendario.com.br/api_feriados_municipais_estaduais_nacionais.php É gratuita, é só colocar o email nessa página.

Comment: Em Portugal mas sem os municipais. https://developers.blogs.sapo.pt/3744.html

Answer (score 13):

Você pode usar o http://holidayapi.com que é uma API que suporta os seguintes países/regiões `BE`, `BR`, `GB`, `NO` or `US` (note que usa o [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) que é versão `alpha`).

Basta fazer uma requisição para o endereço `http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays` que pode ser usado com qualquer linguagem, em C# deve ficar algo como:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=BR&year=2015");

request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

((HttpWebRequest) request).UserAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    response.StatusCode.ToString();
} else {
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    //Converte a resposta para objeto
}
```

Ou pode baixar do GitHub: https://github.com/joshtronic/holidayapi.com (veja a pasta https://github.com/joshtronic/holidayapi.com/tree/master/data)

Como exemplo (infelizmente o repositório é apenas para PHP, mas você pode usar os arquivos `.json`):

```
<?php
require '../lib/HolidayAPIv1.php';
$api = new \HolidayAPI\v1($redis);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$flags = JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;
if (isset($_REQUEST['pretty'])) {
    $flags |= JSON_PRETTY_PRINT;
}
echo json_encode($api->getHolidays(), $flags);
```

Comment: Os feriados para Portugal estão errados

Comment: @SandroMarques está muito vago, de detalhes de como usou, tipo pastebin.

Answer (score 4):

Sem utilizar API, apenas cálculo matemático e a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
function easterDay(y) {
    var c = Math.floor(y / 100);
    var n = y - 19 * Math.floor(y / 19);
    var k = Math.floor((c - 17) / 25);
    var i = c - Math.floor(c / 4) - Math.floor((c - k) / 3) + 19 * n + 15;
    i = i - 30 * Math.floor((i / 30));
    i = i - Math.floor(i / 28) * (1 - Math.floor(i / 28) * Math.floor(29 / (i + 1)) * Math.floor((21 - n) / 11));
    var j = y + Math.floor(y / 4) + i + 2 - c + Math.floor(c / 4);
    j = j - 7 * Math.floor(j / 7);
    var l = i - j;
    var m = 3 + Math.floor((l + 40) / 44);
    var d = l + 28 - 31 * Math.floor(m / 4);
    return moment([y, (m - 1), d]);
};

function getHolidaysBr(y) {
    var anoNovo = moment("01/01/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var carnaval1 = easterDay(y).add(-48, "d");
    var carnaval2 = easterDay(y).add(-47, "d");
    var paixaoCristo = easterDay(y).add(-2, "d");
    var pascoa = easterDay(y);
    var tiradentes = moment("21/04/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var corpusChristi =  easterDay(y).add(60, "d");
    var diaTrabalho = moment("01/05/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var diaIndependencia = moment("07/09/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var nossaSenhora = moment("12/10/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var finados = moment("02/11/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var proclamaRepublica = moment("15/11/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var natal = moment("25/12/"+y,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    return [
        {m: anoNovo, dia: "Ano Novo", d: anoNovo.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: carnaval1, dia: "Carnaval", d: carnaval1.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: carnaval2, dia: "Carnaval", d: carnaval2.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: paixaoCristo, dia: "Paix\u00E3o de Cristo", d: paixaoCristo.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: pascoa, dia: "P\u00E1scoa", d: pascoa.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: tiradentes, dia: "Tiradentes", d: tiradentes.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: corpusChristi, dia: "Corpus Christi", d: corpusChristi.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: diaTrabalho, dia: "Dia do Trabalho", d: diaTrabalho.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: diaIndependencia, dia: "Dia da Independ\u00EAncia do Brasil", d: diaIndependencia.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: nossaSenhora, dia: "Nossa Senhora Aparecida", d: nossaSenhora.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: finados, dia: "Finados", d: finados.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: proclamaRepublica, dia: "Proclama\u00E7\u00E3o da Rep\u00FAblica", d: proclamaRepublica.format("DD/MM/YYYY") },
        {m: natal, dia: "Natal", d: natal.format("DD/MM/YYYY") }
    ];
}
function getHolidayBetweenDates(date, dateTo){
    var dateStart = moment(date,"YYYY-MM-DD");
    var dateEnd = moment(dateTo,"YYYY-MM-DD");
    var datesHoliday = [];

    while (dateEnd > dateStart || dateStart.format("Y") === dateEnd.format("Y")) {
       $.merge(datesHoliday,getHolidaysBr(parseInt(dateStart.format("YYYY"))));
       dateStart.add(1,"year");
    }
    return datesHoliday;
}

var hollidays = getHolidayBetweenDates("2016-01-01","2020-01-01");
```