# Como pegar o próximo dia útil? PHP

Tags: php, e-commerce

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um aplicação PHP relacionada a um Açougue on-line. Na hora de finalizar o pedido, eu tenho que verificar se o horários atual é mais de 17:00 hrs, se for, eu preciso saber qual o próximo dia útil da semana para poder retornar para o cliente a data que será entregue o produto. Alguém pode me ajudar? Procurei em alguns fóruns, mas não encontrei nada parecido.

Comment: Também tem o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50662/descobrir-a-próxima-data-a-partir-do-dia-da-semana/50716#50716. Agora se precisa saber se é feriado ou não tem isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125400/php-verifica-fins-de-semanas-e-feriados e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71221/obter-feriados-nacionais/71226#71226.

Comment: Obrigado brother. Abraço